# Using CONVERT and extracting a week number

Tags: sql-server, date, type-conversion, nvarchar, datepart

I'm trying to get a week number from "EndDate" column (nvarchar data type).
Convert function works fine below.

```
SELECT 
EndDate,
CONVERT(DATE,EndDate,113) as "Date",
```

[Output from the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTA1V.png)

Now, I would like to extract a week number. What would be the best way to do it? I tried datepart() but struggling with incorporating into my convert function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract the weeknumber from a date you can use the datename or datepart tfunction

```
select datename(week, '20220408'),
       datename(iso_week, '20220408'),
       datepart(week, '20220408'),
       datepart(iso_week, '20220408')
```

returns

| COLUMN1 | COLUMN2 | COLUMN6 | COLUMN4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15 | 14 | 15 | 14 |

As for using it in your convert function, why would you want to ?
The function works the same on date and datetime, so just use it like this

```
SELECT EndDate,
       CONVERT(DATE, EndDate, 113) as "Date",
       datepart(week, EndDate)
```

or if you really want to

```
datepart(week, convert(date, EndDate, 113))
```

Comment: Out of interest, why `DATENAME` instead of `DATEPART` (which I would suggest is more appropriate here). Also, `WEEK` and `ISO_WEEK` don't provide the same behaviour, even if you are American.

Comment: @Larnu DateName was the first thing that came to mind, I edited my answer to include all options

Comment: @Larnu As I understand it, in the US they don't use ISO dates, here in Europe we do. This can make a difference off course

Comment: When using `WEEK` the week number is based on the `DATEFIRST` setting. So, for example, `20220102` is week *2* for those with Sunday as the first day of the week (`DATEFIRST` is set to `7`), where as those with it set to Monday (`1`), it would be week *1*.  Conversely, for `ISO_WEEK` is would be week 52, as it's not the first week in the year with a Thursday in it, and ISO Weeks run Monday - Sunday. See [ISO week date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date).

Comment: `WEEK` is *never* carried over to the following year, so any dates prior to the "first" day of the week in the new year would be week 1; if the first day of the week is also 01 Jan, it would obviously be week 1. `ISO_WEEK`s, however, carry over until the 1st week of the next year starts; which is the first week (Monday-Sunday) that contains a Thursday. So as `20220102` was a Sunday, it's the 2nd week for Americans (as a new week has started), the 1st week for Europeans, and the 52nd week (of 2021) in ISO terms.

Comment: @Larnu Yes that is true I know, I am just used to explain it like that here because we have this experience with our american friends that they always use week while we in Europe always use iso_week, our weeknumbers are off by exact this. OK I should have worded it different

Comment: (As a side note, due to many years of working in British retail sector in my Youth, who (at least at the time) commonly used Sunday as the first day of week, my brain still works with Sunday as the first day of the week, despite me being British.)